# How to add mnesia node to existing cluster

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have mnesia installed on a node `a`.
I have already defined a schema and a table.
Now i do not know how can i add another node `b` so that mnesia now can run distributed.

By distributed i mean :

- issue a `insert` of a record in mnesia from node `a`
- be able to fetch the record when querying mnesia of node `b`

What i have tried:

- Start node `a` and start mnesia
- `create_schema` and `create_table` on node `a`
- `dirty_insert` in node `a`

Then

- Start node `b`
- connect node `b` to node `a`
- from node `a` issue : `mnesia:change_config(extra_db_nodes,[nodes()]).` // doesnt matter if i issue this command from node `a` or node `b` i get the following error :

  > (a@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8)7> mnesia:change_config(extra_db_nodes,[nodes()]).
  > =ERROR REPORT==== 3-Jul-2021::13:33:16.147000 === Error in process <0.138.0> on node 'a@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8' with exit value:
  > {function_clause,
  > [{gen_server,do_abcast,
  > [[['b@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8']],
  > mnesia_controller,
  > {'$gen_cast',{merging_schema,'a@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8'}}],
  > [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,263}]},
  > {mnesia_controller,connect_nodes2,3,
  > [{file,"mnesia_controller.erl"},{line,486}]}]}
  >
  > ** exception exit: function_clause
  > in function  gen_server:do_abcast/3
  > called as gen_server:do_abcast([['b@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8']],
  > mnesia_controller,
  > {'$gen_cast',
  > {merging_schema,'a@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8'}})
  > in call from mnesia_controller:connect_nodes2/3 (mnesia_controller.erl, line 486)

I just want any operation i do upon mnesia of a given node to be reflected on the others

Answer (score 2):

`nodes()` already returns a list, so there is no need to wrap the return value in a list.  Try this:

```
mnesia:change_config(extra_db_nodes,nodes()).
```